# Service parameter set other parameters to null in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2016

I have a report with a multi param query that consumes a wcf service.

I set some params with some values:

```
@param1 = 1  
@param2 = 2  
@param3 = "some string"
```

and report works fine but when I set @param4 = 1 or any other value, then

```
@param1 = null  
@param2 = null  
@param3 = null
```

and report just uses @param4 value for the query.

I test the service from a wcf client and the response is right.

How can I find what happens with this param?. I'm using SSRS-2016.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending additional params to the service, I delete these additionals and works fine.